# Chave de array indefinida

Tags: php, array, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Saudações comunidade, estou começando no php e me deparei com um problema que acredito que seja sobre escopo de variáveis.

O projeto é para mostra os divisores primos de um número (guardados no vetor "divisors") e os resultados das divisões (guardados no vetor "results").

O erro que encontro é que não consigo utilizar o índice "$i" dentro do while e do for.

Ao rodar o código, os dois erros que recebo são referentes ao trecho "`if($GLOBALS['num'] % $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'] == 0){`".Os erros são:

**Warning: Undefined array key 25 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTES\calculadora.php on line 17**

**Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTES\calculadora.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTES\calculadora.php on line 17**

```
  $primos = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 
  89, 97);
  

  $num = $_POST["number"];
  $divisors = array();
  $results = array();

  echo "O número é $num";
  
  for($i = 0; $i <= count($primos); $i++){

    $p_nums = $GLOBALS['primos'];
    $i_atual = $i;

    if($GLOBALS['num'] % $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'] == 0){
      $GLOBALS['divisors'][] = $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'];

      $GLOBALS['num'] /= $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'];
      $GLOBALS['results'][] = $GLOBALS['num'];

      while($GLOBALS['num'] % $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'] == 0){
        $GLOBALS['num'] /= $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'];
        $GLOBALS['results'][] = $GLOBALS['num'];
      }
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que você está encontrando é porque você falou para o seu código contar a quantidade de itens no array e fazer o for esta quantidade de vezes. Tem 25 valores no array então ele tenta fazer do 0 até ser igual a 25 (o que dá 26x).
Você não pode corrigir isso mudando o início porque as posições do array começam no 0 então você tem que mandar ele fazer o for até valor menor do que o número de itens do array, ele vai executar do 0 ao 24, que também da 25x, mas começando a contar do 0:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($primos); $i++)
```

Comment: Uma outra coisa também, que não faz parte da pergunta, é que você usa o tempo todo $GLOBALS['primos[$i]'], mas dentro do for você define $p_nums = $GLOBALS['primos']; então não precisaria usar a variável global dentro do for, já que já copiou os dados ali pra dentro...

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, consertei|!